# How to call a php page from Facebook "like" button JS code?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I looked through some answers and I can't seem to get anything to work.  Now I am wondering if this is because the site I am working on is currently only visible locally through XAMPP.

Here are a couple of code snippets of what I've tried:

```
<script> 
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', location.href = 'test.php');
</script>
```

and

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "test.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
});
```

The facebook code seems to run but my php page is never called.  Even a simple alert('You liked the URL: '); doesn't work.  I can "like" the page and it shows-up in my FB wall as such.

This is what I have right after the body tag (copy-paste from FB):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I saw a post somewhere claiming that if the URL being liked didn't match the URL where the button was clicked from this would not work.  Well, I am clicking from "www.site-name.local" when the real URL is a .com.  It seems to work as far as the liked URL showing-up on my FB wall but the even does not fire.

I just checked the Firebug console and I get:

```
FB is not defined
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
```

I'd appreciate a shove in the right direction.

Comment: So you have tried. And? Any results?

Comment: Edited original post to answer your question

Comment: How are you determining that the Facebook code "seems to run" if none of your code ever gets executed?

Comment: You'll need to define the call back function xmlhttp.onreadystatechange. Are you sure that the page isn't called?

Comment: @MichaelMior - Because when I go to my Facebook page the URL shows-up as having been liked by me.  The only way this can happen is if the FB code ran when I clicked the button.  The only thing that isn't happening is that my php page is not loading after I post to FB.

Comment: have you been debugging with firebug? can you tell me if the js sdk is being loaded asynchronously or sync? can you show where you have put the event subscribes?

Comment: @bool.dev I edited the post to include some of this information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's the solution.  It may not be THE solution, but it worked for me.

The code and explanation posted on the FB Dev site here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Great Web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div class="fb-like"></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Worked fine as far as later on being able to "like" a page and having that show-up on FB, but it did not trigger any action once the button is clicked.

I decided to go get an App ID for the site.  This made it all work.

The new code looks like this:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'my_app_ID_number', // App ID
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    oauth      : true,
  });
  // Additional initialization code here

  // Get notified when user likes this
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response){location.href = 'test.php'});            
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
```

I had to place "FB.Event.subscribe" within this code block or it would cause an error.  "FB.Event.subscribe" seemed to run before "FB.init" got a chance to do its job.  Not sure how you'd go about doing this if you had multiple "Like" buttons on a single page.

Anyhow, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure FB.init is called before the FB.Event.subscribe can fire.

Comment: Sure looks like it fixed it.  From your answer above, you indeed moved the FB.Event.subscribe to just after the FB.init() call.

Comment: What I meant is that just moving FB.Event.Subscribe didn't fix the problem.  That alone was not the solution.

Comment: A quote from your answer below: "*I had to place "FB.Event.subscribe" within this code block or it would cause an error. "FB.Event.subscribe" seemed to run before "FB.init" got a chance to do its job.*"  Which is EXACTLY what I suggested to you to do.